# number unite adjective

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, adjectives

1. Please give me a two hour leave
2. Please give me two hours leave

   Providing that those are correct, Could you tell me when/ in which situation you would rather use one over the other?

   Meanwhile, would you tell me if I have well rephrased number 1?

   a two hour(long) leave

Comment: In the first sentence, hyphen is required. Please grant me a two-hour leave. The second one is correct if it has *apostrophe*. Please grant me two hours' leave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you form adjectives from numbers there are two factors to bear in mind:

1. Number adjectives are **always** hyphenated:

> **two-hour** leave
>
> **three-mile** hike
>
> **five-year-old** child

1. Unlike in other languages, English adjectives are **never** pluralized. By way of contrast, in Spanish the adjective **ciego** *blind (person)*, can be made plural **ciegos** *blind (people)*. Not so in English - so much so that even the counted element in a numerical adjective takes a singular form:

> two hours ➝ **two-hour**
>
> three miles ➝ **three-mile**
>
> five years old ➝ **five-year-old**

Comment: Could we use the plural form if we apply the possessive **'s**: "Give me two hours' leave"? Such usage seems to be OK in some cases, like "I have two years' experience in..". 
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119751/one-plus-years-experience-in

Comment: Yes, because then it ceases to be adjectival and becomes partitive in nature, i.e. the same as saying "two years of experience" or "two hours of leave"